# Adding time to jQuery datepicker() function

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a input field which I want to fill with date and time in format yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss, because I'm sending this information to my databases column with DATETIME (or similar) data type. I made this work with two inputs - one textfield I filled with datepicker() and other was `<select>` list with predefined values for time. Today I was coding another functionality in php and I didn`t like my situation with date and time, so I made javascript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datepicker").click(function(){
        var a = "yy-mm-dd ";
        var b = prompt("Ievadi laiku formātā hh-mm-ss", "00-00-00");    
    var c = a.concat(b);
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: c});
        });
    </script>
```

So when I click on the input field I get a prompt where I type time and press enter. This is when I'd like to choose a date from the calendar but as datepicker actually works at the same time when prompt shows up (on click), then argument c doesn't exist at this time and calendar doesn't show up because dateFormat is invalid. If I click once again on the input field, I get another prompt and after the second prompt calendar shows up, but datepicker uses the format I was trying to set the first time not now. So if I entered "00-00-00" for the first time and "00-10-00" for the second, than after choosing the date I get "mydate 00-00-00" and not the actual time I entered this time. I've seen similar posts here but it didn't help me. There was a post of getting current time and appending to the date but I guess this is different. Should I use some other method to enter the time and then add it to date as I was trying to do it or is there a way to give my variable c a value before datepicker works? I`ll appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: date and time are somewhat less cared web specs. 

the behavior [varies much][1] between desktop and mobile browsers.

if you need a more reliable solution you should look for a richer datepicker component, a few searches will pop many [decent options][2].

  [1]: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime
  [2]: https://www.google.com?q=ui%20angular%20datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datepicker").click(function(){
        var a = "yy-mm-dd ";
        var b = prompt("Ievadi laiku formātā hh-mm-ss", "00-00-00");    
    var c = a.concat(b);
    if (c.length > 0){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: c});
        }});

    </script>
```

If statement solved this one. But it doesn`t work every time. I`ll check this tomorrow.

EDITED: this works - https://jsfiddle.net/gne64yd5/20/

Comment: If you have answered your own question, you should accept the answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gne64yd5/20/ this is how I finnaly got everything work the way I wanted.